# Ubuntus desktop

Tags: unity, cinnamon

Okay so is there a way that I can use the desktop part of ubuntu like windows?  In the sense that applications and programs are clickable on the desktop?  I can't seem to figure anything out and cinnamon isn't working for me on 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag an application icon from the Unity dash, to the background, it should create an icon there which you could double-click on to launch the app.

If it doesn't work, there's a bug in either Unity, Nautilus, or both, that broke it perhaps. Granted it's not a common action, so may have slipped through the cracks. You should file a bug about it not working. For a workaround, you can copy the `.desktop` file for the application you want to see there, from `/usr/share/applications/` into `~/Desktop/`, and run `chmod +x application.desktop` or right-click on the file, and choose `Properties`, switch to the `Permissions` tab, and toggle the `[] Allow executing file as program` option in there. The file will then show up with the correct icon and application name.